# Last ListItem always receives ontouch event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listview  in my app. Each listitem has an icon on the left and some text on the right.
I wish to show some animation when the icon is clicked. I have used ontouch listener, where animation begins when the on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event and some other action takes place  on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event.

The issue is that when I click a particular item in a listview, the icon gets animated for that particular item as well as the last item in the listview.. everytime.. Not sure what the issue may be. Kindly help.

The relevant portion of code is pasted below:

```
public class Accounts implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, AnimationListener{

Animation animation1;
ImageButton folderBTN;

//oncreate method
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);



    //Adapter getview method
    ..
    .
    .
    .
    getView(){

        folderBTN.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    folderBTN.clearAnimation();
                    folderBTN.setAnimation(animation1);
                    folderBTN.startAnimation(animation1);
                    isIconShowing=true;

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    FolderList.actionHandleAccount(Accounts.this,
                            (Account) account);
                }
                return false;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. The imagebutton folderbtn in the above code contains reference to the last view generated. Using a different variable fixed the issue for me. This is the code in case someone might need it.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        toAnimateBTN=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.folders);
                        toAnimateBTN.clearAnimation();
                        toAnimateBTN.setAnimation(animation2);
                        toAnimateBTN.startAnimation(animation2);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are reusing the same animation instance, try to declare the animation instance inside onTouch method. Try the following code snippet.

```
 public class Accounts implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, AnimationListener{


    ImageButton folderBTN;

    //oncreate method


        //Adapter getview method
        ..
        .
        .
        .
        getView(){

            folderBTN.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            Animation animation;
                            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
                            animation.setAnimationListener(Accounts.this);


                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        folderBTN.clearAnimation();
                        folderBTN.setAnimation(animation);
                        folderBTN.startAnimation(animation);
                        isIconShowing=true;

                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        FolderList.actionHandleAccount(Accounts.this,
                                (Account) account);
                    }
                    return false;
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: thanks.. I will try this.. But I am wondering why this is happenning for the last item in the listview..